# Installing Emacs in custom directory (on OS X)

Tags: macos, installation, emacs, path

Fed up with emacs22 that came with Xcode, I set out to upgrade to emacs24. I do not want to overwrite the system defaults, and do not want to mess up with it either, so I tried to install emacs in a custom directory other than `/usr/local/`.

Say I set the prefix to `CUSTOM_DIR/emacs-24.2`. I built and installed emacs 24.2 to the `CUSTOM_DIR/emacs-24.2` directory, so `bin/`, `libexec/`, `share/`, and `var/` are all there. (Yes, I have manually checked all required files; the installation is totally complete in the custom directory.) But when I tried to run the new version of emacs, I got the following error messages:

```
Warning: arch-dependent data dir (/usr/local/libexec/emacs/24.2/x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1/) does not exist.
Warning: arch-independent data dir (/usr/local/share/emacs/24.2/etc/) does not exist.
Warning: Lisp directory `/usr/local/share/emacs/24.2/site-lisp' does not exist.
Warning: Lisp directory `/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp' does not exist.
Warning: Lisp directory `/usr/local/share/emacs/24.2/lisp' does not exist.
Warning: Lisp directory `/usr/local/share/emacs/24.2/leim' does not exist.
Error: charsets directory not found:
/usr/local/share/emacs/24.2/etc/charsets
Emacs will not function correctly without the character map files.
Please check your installation!
```

So obviously emacs's search path was not affected despite the option `--prefix=CUSTOM_DIR/emacs-24.2` I specified when running `configure`. How do I fix this? Is there any configuration files I need to change, or do I need to add some configuration options when configuring and building emacs? (I built emacs 24.2 from tarball.)

P.S. Please do not suggest other ways of installation. I *do* know how to install emacs 24, either by installing to `/usr/local/`, which appeared to have no problem at all; or with MacPorts or similar projects; or by directly running from the command line component found in Emacs.app binary distribution. I simply want to fix this very problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Dror Well, thanks, but perhaps you did not read the last paragraph. I know a couple ways for what I want; I just want to solve the problem at hand, since it shouldn't have occurred.

Comment: @Dror As you can see, you suggestion has already been listed in the last paragraph. I've known that approach well.

Comment: Sorry. My bad! I missed the last paragraph indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago I used to build emacs from source:

```
git://git.savannah.gnu.org/emacs.git
```

in a custom dir with:

```
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=$HOME/cmp/soft/sft/Emacs --enable-link-time-optimization
make bootstrap
make install
```

Comment: Well, what should I say... I've long given this up, but thanks for answering anyways.